# Zepto.js: Tap event doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, iphone, zepto

Heyo,

I'm using Zepto (zeptojs.com). This is literally my whole code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>Tap me!</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="zepto.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("div").on("tap", function() {
    alert("Tapped!");
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Running it in iPhone-Simulator on Mac, nothing happens when I tap the `<div>`. When I change `tap` to `touchend`, the `alert` will show up.

I'm obviously doing something wrong here... But what?

Comment: Ok, I forgot to include the touch-module... :D Thought it is implemented by default.
So: You have to include this file to your document, too: https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/master/src/touch.js#files

Answer (score 1):

By default the touch module is not included into zepto dist. You can link the file, or you can make your own build with the touch module added.

Simply clone the source from github and edit the makefile. The list of the modules in in target.built section.

```
...
target.build = ->
  cd __dirname
  mkdir '-p', 'dist'
  modules = (env['MODULES'] || 'zepto detect event ajax form fx touch').split(' ')
  module_files = ( "src/#{module}.js" for module in modules )
  ...
```